# LiScroll - Auto Update <UL> from PHP file after each scroll

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working with LiScroll:
http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html

I'm trying to get it to load the contents dynamically from a PHP file before each scroll.

I've attempted to change the `<ul>` which it reads from with the following ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "tickertext.php",
context: document.body
}).done(function(response) {
$('ul#ticker01').replaceWith(response);
});
```

However, I was not able to get this to work correctly.

Has anyone had any experience with LiScroll/ajax and could help me out please?

Comment: "However, I was not able to get this to work correctly." What is the error, exactly? It would be nice to elabourate on that. Have you checked your error console?

Comment: I've tried inserting the above AJAX into the LiScroll JS function: function scrollnews(spazio, tempo) However, I think it tries to run repeatedly as it quickly overflows with the error: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" I'm not sure where I should be adding this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I was adding the ajax in the wrong place. The ticker is now updating from my PHP file.